# How does apps like WhatApp can get rid of the connection limit to the Apple Push Notification Services?

Tags: ios, scalability, apple-push-notifications

The Apple APNS only allow up to `20` max connections from your server, so how does apps like WhatApp is able to deliver such high volume of message per seconds?

Even they can use multiple servers, but assuming they have 5M active users sending message, they also need 250K servers, that sound crazy, right?

What is the trick here?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: You don't need one connection per user.

You can send multiple messages per APNS connection. Each message can be sent to a different device. The maximum payload length is 256 bytes plus 45 bytes of overhead; a 10Mbit connection can handle *at least* 4100 messages per second, or about 250k/min, or about 3 per hour per user.

Does the average "active user" send more than 3 per hour? It's hard to tell. "Active" might mean that they sent a message that month; such distributions have *very long* tails.

Either way, that's for a *single* 10M connection. I'm not sure how much contention there is on Apple's side, but it would not surprise me if you could exceed 50M without too much fuss.

Additionally, they almost certainly use their own servers when the app is in the foreground, and if they're clever they can keep the connection open for a few minutes after the app is backgrounded (and only use push notifications once the connection closes).